# Is there a smart way to tag all your AWS resources with the same tag?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, tagging

I know that you can easily find all the resources which are associated with a certain tag but does any one have a smart way to update or add a tag to different types of AWS resources using their ARN tag?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't use this. But seems to be what you are looking for: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ARG/latest/userguide/tag-editor.html

Now, I don't think you can use the web-console if you want the tags to be dynamic (different per resource). So probably you are going to have to use AWS CLI, AWS SDK or Terraform(?) so you can use a variable like `${resource.ARN}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [resourcegroupstaggingapi](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/resourcegroupstaggingapi/index.html), or the [Boto3 equivelant](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/resourcegroupstaggingapi.html). The API exposes endpoints for getting all resources (including their ARN's) and for tagging a list of resources by supplying a list of ARN's.

A Boto3 example use of the tagging may look like this:

```
client = boto3.client('resourcegroupstaggingapi', "eu-west-1")    
client.tag_resources(
    ResourceARNList=["arn1", "arn2"],
    Tags={"key": "val"}
)
```

Here is a [Git repository](https://github.com/karimtabet/aws_tag_all) that gets all resources in every region and tags them with a supplied dictionary of tags.